# Replace string with space using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file like this:

```
{
    value                =        yes
    enabled              =        yes
}
```

and I need to edit enable="yes" to "no".

Comment: `sed -i 's/yes/no/g' filename`

Comment: sorry, I re-edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i '/enabled/s/yes/no/g' filename
```